# keyboard input with ctrl,alt, shift + key

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-events, alt

I am coding some keyboard inputs to my code, but i'm having trouble figuring out how to get the keys that require a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> input as well.
I tried this but this just make the key work as soon as i press the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.
I am trying to use the <kbd>+</kbd> button that is not on the numpad.

```
Case Keys.ShiftKey And Keys.Oemplus
            BTB_plus.PerformClick()
```

And Using `keys.Shift` does nothing at all

Also, if someone has a list of which key has what name in VB.NET, it would be appreciated. (or good tutorials on this subject)

Would prefer if someone could post the code for a select case statement, thx

Comment: F1 on Control.ModifierKeys and Keys Enumeration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use case statement I would then perform this:

```
Dim bHandled As Boolean = False
    Select Case e.Modifiers
        Case Keys.Control
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Oemplus Then
                MsgBox("KeyPress CTRL + OEMPLUS")
                e.Handled = True
            End If

            If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
                MsgBox("KeyPress CTRL + A")
                e.Handled = True
            End If


        Case Keys.Shift
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Oemplus Then
                MsgBox("KeyPress Shift + OEMPLUS")
                e.Handled = True
            End If

            If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
                MsgBox("KeyPress Shift + A")
                e.Handled = True
            End If

    End Select
```

Comment: Thankx! but what is the `bHandled` for? I don't see it being used again in the code after its deceleration. or is it a typo?

Comment: I am sorry you do not need the bHandled portion.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there :)

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Oemplus And e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
    MsgBox("KeyPress CTRL + OEMPLUS")
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx

Comment: I have my keyboard inputs written in a select case statement, would you happen to know how to write it for that? 
`Case Keys.Oemplus And e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift
                BTB_plus.PerformClick()
                e.Handled = True`

This code gives me an error for the `e.modifiers = keys.shif` part